# Adding token image into smart contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets

can we directly add the token logo to the token smart-contract so that we can visualize it in Wallets and Exchanges and so that we don’t have to register it in another way
Please help
erc20 token standard

Answer (score 1):

The ERC20 standard has no way of adding a logo to it. And in general, you shouldn't store images in the blockchain, since data storage is extremely expensive in Ethereum.

It's up to various external services to store the logo and to retrieve it from various places. You have to consult the documentation of the services you want to use.